# Comparator alternative , if 2 attributes have same value

Tags: java, spring-boot, comparator

Currently I am working on a scenario in which I have to find minimum Timestamp and have to print corresponding amount and second scenario is suppose If Timestamp of 2 data is same then I have to print timestamp and sum of both the amount. I am not able to achieve the second scenario through comparator. If you people have some solution or any alternative please let me know.

Code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
 
class Student {
    private String timestamp;
    private int amount;
 
    public Student(String timestamp, int amount) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
        this.amount = amount;
    }
 
    public String getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }
 
    public int getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }
 
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student{" +
                "timestamp='" + timestamp + '\'' +
                ", amount=" + amount +
                '}';
    }
}
 
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        List<Student> students = Arrays.asList(
                new Student("2022-06-06 14:19:37.000", 25),
                new Student("2022-06-06 14:19:37.000", 15),
        );
 
        
 
        Comparator<Student> timestampComparator = Comparator
      .comparing(Student::getTimestamp);
    Student earliestDate = students.stream()
      .min(timestampComparator)
      .get();
    }
}
```

The expected output-
2022-06-06 14:19:37.000, 40

Output that I am getting-
2022-06-06 14:19:37.000, 25

Comment: Just to clarify, do you need to compare those timestamps as actual timestamps, or as strings(lexicographic order)? Currently you are doing the lexicographic ordering.

Comment: @Chaosfire I have to compare those timestamps as actual Timestamps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a `Comparator`, what you need is to group and aggregate the result.

Since you need actual dates, you should use [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html), the modern java date time API. For simplicity i'll use LocalDateTime and assume all students are in the same(default) timezone. Changed student class:

```
public class Student {

  private static final DateTimeFormatter FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");

  private final LocalDateTime timestamp;
  private final int amount;

  public Student(String timestamp, int amount) {
    this.timestamp = LocalDateTime.parse(timestamp, FORMATTER);
    this.amount = amount;
  }

  public LocalDateTime getTimestamp() {
    return timestamp;
  }

  public int getAmount() {
    return amount;
  }
}
```

Note how i'm parsing the strings to `LocalDateTime`.

The actual grouping and aggregation of data;

```
public class Temp {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Student> students = Arrays.asList(new Student("2022-06-06 14:19:37.000", 25),
            new Student("2022-06-06 14:19:37.000", 15),
            new Student("2022-06-06 14:19:38.000", 15));
    Map.Entry<LocalDateTime, Integer> result = students.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Student::getTimestamp, Student::getAmount, Integer::sum, TreeMap::new))
            .firstEntry();
    System.out.println(result.getKey() + ", " + result.getValue());
  }
}
```

I am collecting data into `Map<LocalDateTime, Integer>`, keys are timestamps, values are sums of amount for each student with this timestamp.

1. `Student::getTimestamp` - function generating key for the map, by extracting the timestamp of the student.
2. `Student::getAmount` - function generating value for the key, by extracting amount for the student.
3. `Integer::sum` - merge function, handles key collisions(key already exists), the value is replaced by the current value + new amount.
4. `TreeMap::new` - function, supplying the map, where the data is collected. I am using `TreeMap` because it is sorted by the key and it's easy to extract the key/value pair with minimum key.

Refer to the docs of [Collectors.toMap()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-java.util.function.Supplier-) for additional info.

Answer (score 1):

You want to first group by your timestamp and calculate the sum for each timestamp (if there's only a single item for this timestamp, the sum will be this item's value only). This doesn't require a comparator. Next, find the minimum timestamp and return the sum (this is where the comparator comes into play).

```java
int value = students.stream()
  .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Student::getTimestamp, Collectors.summingInt(Student::getValue)))
  .entrySet()
  .stream()
  .min(Map.Entry.compareByKey())
  .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
  .findFirst()
  .orElse(0);
```

Comment: That's the proper way of addressing the problem of finding the Value associated with the lowest Key - grouping by `timestamp` and performing a linear search instead of sorting.

Comment: Alternatively, combination of *comparators* `groupingBy` + `summingInt` can be replaced with three-args flavor of `toMap` - `Collectors.toMap(Student::getTimestamp, Student::getAmount, Integer::sum)`.

Answer (score 0):

You need a second cycle to build the sum.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    List<Student> students = Arrays.asList(
            new Student("2022-06-06 14:19:37.000", 25),
            new Student("2022-06-06 14:19:37.000", 15));

    Comparator<Student> timestampComparator = Comparator
            .comparing(Student::getTimestamp);
    Student earliestDate = students.stream()
            .min(timestampComparator)
            .get();
    int sum = students.stream()
            .filter(s-> earliestDate.getTimestamp().equals(s.getTimestamp()))
            .mapToInt(Student::getAmount).sum();
    Student sumStudent = new Student(earliestDate.getTimestamp(), sum);
    System.out.println(sumStudent);
}
```